# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 10712) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

it is actually my first time using TensorFlow for image recognition and while testing this code here I got this error and could not fix the problem for like 2 days now , however i tyred to rechape the X and Y but same thing , my goal is to train a model to automatically read correctly a printed image of a number

please help and thank you in advance

````
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)  # y labels are oh-encoded

n_train = mnist.train.num_examples  # 55,000
n_validation = mnist.validation.num_examples  # 5000
n_test = mnist.test.num_examples  # 10,000

n_input = 784  # input layer (28x28 pixels)
n_hidden1 = 512  # 1st hidden layer
n_hidden2 = 256  # 2nd hidden layer
n_hidden3 = 128  # 3rd hidden layer
n_output = 10  # output layer (0-9 digits)

learning_rate = 1e-4
n_iterations = 1000
batch_size = 128
dropout = 0.5

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_output])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

weights = {
    'w1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_hidden1], stddev=0.1)),
    'w2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden1, n_hidden2], stddev=0.1)),
    'w3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden2, n_hidden3], stddev=0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden3, n_output], stddev=0.1)),
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden3])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_output]))
}

layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['w1']), biases['b1'])
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['w2']), biases['b2'])
layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['w3']), biases['b3'])
layer_drop = tf.nn.dropout(layer_3, keep_prob)
output_layer = tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['out']) + biases['out']

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=Y, logits=output_layer
        ))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output_layer, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# train on mini batches
for i in range(n_iterations):
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={
        X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: dropout
        })

    # print loss and accuracy (per minibatch)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        minibatch_loss, minibatch_accuracy = sess.run(
            [cross_entropy, accuracy],
            feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0}
            )
        print(
            "Iteration",
            str(i),
            "\t| Loss =",
            str(minibatch_loss),
            "\t| Accuracy =",
            str(minibatch_accuracy)
            )

test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, Y: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
print("\nAccuracy on test set:", test_accuracy)
img = np.invert(Image.open("C:\\Users\\ADEM\\Desktop\\msi_youssef\\PFE\\test\\numbers\\rafik1.png").convert('L')).ravel()

prediction = sess.run(tf.argmax(output_layer, 1), feed_dict={X: [img]})
print ("Prediction for test image:", np.squeeze(prediction))```
````

Comment: error in :  
prediction = sess.run(tf.argmax(output_layer, 1), feed_dict={X: [img]})

Comment: If the error is in that line, your model is running well but fail at the prediction ? What is the shape of 'img' ? Can you print it to debug ?

Comment: The error is telling you the exact issue. You have trained your model on the images of 28 X 28 i.e. 784 dimensional vector of pixels (after flattening). Now, you are trying to use the trained model to predict the class using an image of 10712 pixels. You will have to compress it to 28 X 28 first and then flatten it out. Basically, it should match the dimensions of the training data images.